# NodeJS cannot upload file cause upstream prematurely closed connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

When created a website with nodejs. In this website I have a page that can upload image to server. I tested this on my computer it's work fine. After I deploy it to server it's not working. I read the log. I got two from both access and error log at the same time.

This is an error.log

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream , client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: example.com, request: "POST /admin/place/thumbnanil/upload HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/admin/place/thumbnanil/upload", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/admin/place/detail"
```

This is an access.log

```
POST /admin/place/thumbnanil/upload HTTP/1.1" 502 583 "https://example.com/admin/place/detail"
```

This is my nginx virtual host

```
upstream example {
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
   listen                   80;
   server_name              example.com;
   return                   301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen                   443 ssl;
   server_name              example.com;
   ssl_certificate          /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key      /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
   location / {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

           proxy_buffering on;
           proxy_buffer_size 8k;
           proxy_buffers 2048 8k;
   }
}
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 on AWS EC2.
NodeJS v4.4.7

This is the url that I'm using for post : https://example.com/admin/place/thumbnanil/upload

Comment: Can you post the full url that you are using to post?

Comment: @AkshayKumar Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass          http://localhost:3002/;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffering     off;
    proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3002/  https://example.com/;

}
```

Comment: Edited try it now

Comment: I still got the same error but this time I got error about folder permission I will fix it and try again.

Comment: It's work sir. can you explain to me why my configuration is not work please.

Comment: I think the issue was with proxy redirect you were not redirecting your domain url to your local server url ``proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3002/  https://example.com/`` and you have set ``proxy_buffering`` which might be creating issue. Nginx proxy_buffering is explained in more details http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html